# Problems with Django model relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've little problem with django models. I'm trying to create a game statistics service, but can't figure out how could I pick players from each team as a starting roster (doesn't contain all of the team players) of the game. Picking should work so that home and visitor has separated player lists. And then it should be possible to create eg Goal object where I could pick player as scorer only from the starting roster. I've already tried to put home and visitor players as ManyToManyField in the Game model, but it won't work. It needs some filtering at least.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, related_name="game_series")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="game_home")
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="game_visitor")


class Goal(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game,  related_name="goal_game")
    minutes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    seconds = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    scorer = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="goal_scorer")
    assist = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="goal_assist")


class Save(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name="save_game")
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="save_player")
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

The question is: how should I modify models to achieve the desired result? Note: I'm using admin views for data input, so the proposed resolution should work from there.

EDIT: There is also Player model which I forgot to explain earlier. So, both of teams has already defined list of players where to pick roster for the game.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="player_team")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: So you want to construct two teams based on a (not given) list of `Player`s? What are the constraints on these teams (number of participants, skills players need to have, etc.)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I added explanation about the Player model